# WPF Shortcut Key not firing

Tags: wpf, prism

I have a prism delegate command setup for refresh the data in my application.
I also have setup shortcuts for close and about window using delegate command.

Using F5 also does not trigger the refresh in the view model. If I use Alt+F4, the application closes. But it does not execute the CloseApplication method in the view model. What is missing in the following code to execute the ViewModel using the Gesture Shorcuts?

UserControl:

```
<UserControl.InputBindings>
    <KeyBinding Gesture="ALT+F4" Command="{Binding CloseCommand}" />
    <KeyBinding Gesture="F5" Command="{Binding RefreshCommand}" />
</UserControl.InputBindings>
<DockPanel>
    <Menu DockPanel.Dock="Top">
        <MenuItem Header="_File">
            <MenuItem Header="E_xit" Command="{Binding CloseCommand}" InputGestureText="Alt+F4" />
            <MenuItem Header="Refresh" Command="{Binding RefreshCommand}" InputGestureText="F5" />
        </MenuItem>
        <MenuItem Header="_Help">
            <MenuItem Header="_About" Command="{Binding AboutCommand}" />
        </MenuItem>
    </Menu>
    <ToolBar ToolBarTray.IsLocked="True">
        <Button Content="Home" MinHeight="50" MinWidth="80" VerticalContentAlignment="Bottom" />
        <Button Content="Page 1" MinHeight="50" MinWidth="80" VerticalContentAlignment="Bottom" />
        <Button Content="Page 2" MinHeight="50" MinWidth="80" VerticalContentAlignment="Bottom" />
    </ToolBar>
</DockPanel>
```

ViewModel of the UserControl

```
public class TopMenuViewModel:NotificationObject
    {
        private DelegateCommand _closeCommand;
        private DelegateCommand _aboutCommand;
        private DelegateCommand _refreshCommand;

        public TopMenuViewModel()
        {
            _closeCommand = new DelegateCommand(CloseApplication);
            _aboutCommand = new DelegateCommand(ShowAboutWindow);
            _refreshCommand = new DelegateCommand(RefreshApplication);
        }

        private void ShowAboutWindow()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Show about window");
        }

        private void CloseApplication()
        {
            Application.Current.Shutdown();
        }

        private void RefreshApplication()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Refreshing..");
        }

        public ICommand CloseCommand 
        {
            get { return _closeCommand; }
        }

        public ICommand AboutCommand
        {
            get { return _aboutCommand; }
        }

        public ICommand RefreshCommand
        {
            get { return _refreshCommand; }
        }


    }
```

The view model methods are called if I use the mouse to click the menu or use the Alt+x or Alt+A. But not using the KeyBinding that I have put in. Thanks for your help.

Comment: you said it does close when pressing Alt+F4 
?

Comment: Yes. But it does not call CloseApplication(). I am thinking it may be due to the windows default behavior? It closes all applications whether you define any key gestures or not?

Comment: than change the gesture , it sounds like windows is handling your 
command , so the application is closed by the os and your method is never called .

Comment: I found why the refresh is not called. It is due to focus issue. The user control does not have focus when the application loads and hence the keybindings don't fire. For AltF4 I let the behavior as it is and handle the close events to do my work.

Comment: I have the same problem (only focused UserControl fires the keybindings). There must be a solution to this since this is the way PRISM is working. I have lots of UserControls which are loaded into the ShellView and would like to define some keyboard shortcuts PER VIEW/UserControl. Any idea someone?